# Javascript document.getElementsByName( ) with array assigned based on variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, function, variables

These are the checkboxes I currently have [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rqqa.png) and when I click on the first checkbox 'April 2015' it should show like this [checkedAll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tw4X.png).
My current checkboxes name is created based on the loop $i `name='check_all[".$i."]'`. and the checkboxes should be named as "

> `checkbox[1], checkbox[2],..` "

but in javascript, how should I let enter the loop number into the `document.getElementsByName("check_all[]")`. The loop is based on the database row, so I don't want to make it hard coded. How do I let the `document.getElementsByName("check_all[]")` get the

> `document.getElementsByName("check_all[2]") or document.getElementsByName("check_all[3]")`

based on the function.

**Function**

```
public function showMY(){ 
..other codes...
$i = 1;
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($viewSQL)) {
    $MY= $row['MY'];
    echo "<tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox' name='' onclick=\"toggle2(this); showMe2('divCheckbox');\" >
          </td>
          <tr>
          <td><input type='checkbox' class='some_cls' name='check_all[".$i."]' value='' onclick='showMe2('divCheckbox')'></td>";
$i++;
}
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function toggle2(source) {
  var checkboxesCls = document.querySelectorAll('input.some_cls');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxesCls.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxesCls[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}

function showMe2 (box) {
    var chboxs = document.querySelectorAll('input.some_cls');
    var vis = "none";
    for(var i=0;i<chboxs.length;i++) { 
        if(chboxs[i].checked){
         vis = "inline";
            break;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(box).style.display = vis;
}
```

I had a very hard time solving this, please help.

**Edited: 
This is the latest code I had implemented.. The current problem is that it will auto check for the data below "Jan 2016" when I just want to check all for the data below "April 2015". [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq3jT.png)**

Comment: Your loop generates invalid markup because it's missing the closing `</tr>` tags. The `</tr>` is only in very specific cases allowed to be omitted: https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element

Comment: For your actual problem/question: add a class, use `.querySelectorAll()` or use DOM traversal to get the correct checkboxes.

Comment: @Andreas yes I missed out the </tr> when copying codes here. Okay. Thank you for the advice, I'll try it again!!

Comment: If you know the indices beforehand, why not just check for those two indices only? `if(chboxs[2].checked || if(chboxs[3].checked) {...}`. That way you don't need the loop at all.

Comment: @Teemu As the array number is based on the database row. It shouldn't be hard coded as the rows will be increased when record is entered. It will have more than 10 chboxs or even more.

Comment: Your loop generates two checkboxes on each iteration. I don't see how that could generate what you have provided as image. It seems to me that there should be a loop around that second checkbox. So... how did you produce that image?

Comment: @trincot there is still a while loop to generate the rows from database. those checkboxes are based on database rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class attribute in input tag:

```
"<input type='checkbox' class='some_cls' name='check_all[".$i."]' onclick=\"toggle2(this); showMe2('divCheckbox');\" >"
```

Then, in javascript use `querySelectorAll()`:

```
var chboxs = document.querySelectorAll('input .some_cls');
```

Comment: I had already use the querySelectorAll(), but still have the issue where it will check all the checkboxes in the table. I just want the specific "April 2015" but it also check for the row below "Jan 2016".